# How to create categories out of a list of words?

Tags: php, categories

I have a simple text file with a list of words (Berlin Hamburg Stuttgart ...) and so on. They are cities of germany an nearly 2000 counted. I need everyone of them as a category in my wordpress site and looking for the best way to achieve this. Is there a faster way than to create every single category manually from the dashboard?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a nice list of your Words, you could easily create an `array` with them, doing a little data manipulation.

Afterwards you can loop throug your `$array` and insert the Term accordingly:

```
$yourcities = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all your valuesfrom the .txt file

foreach( $yourcities as $thiscity ) {

    wp_insert_term(
        $thiscity, // the term, in your case the name of the city
        'category', // the taxonomy, in your case category
        array(
            'description'=> '', // if available
            'slug' => '', // leave blank if not available
            'parent'=> $parent_term_id // if you do it hierarchical, be sure to insert the parent ID here
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But how do I have to do it? I have just a text-document with a list of words. What should I exactly do with it?

Comment: Try doing it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element). I updated the answer to include this method :)

Comment: Okay and where do I have to place the code exactly and store the txt. file?

Comment: You can store the code in your `functions.php` or create a plugin for it. The easiest way would be to upload the `.txt` into the same folder. Be sure to execute the code only once!

Comment: 2 more things: It's not the default category for posts, it's the taxonomy=ad_location from the posttype=ad.

The text-file is calles staedte.txt and located now in the same folder like the function.php.

How does the code looks now for me?

Comment: You just have to change `category` for `ad_location`, that's all :)

Comment: And where d i have to put in the name staedte.txt of the text file? (=

Comment: this is the `$filename`.

Comment: I just get this 2 messages:
 No such file or directory in ... function.php
and
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()? :(